# Xamarin Agent losing connection during build with one specific solution

Tags: ios, xamarin, build

This becomes more and more frustrating fighting xamarin MacAgent bugs when building for iOS from Windows.. With those build freezes then killing VS process 50 times a day, other nice freezes due to bad resources names (you mistake and put a Cyrillic "х" instead of latin "x" in a filename), now today i have fought a constant MacAgent disconnects during build with just one specific project.

That was a real something as other solutions for iOS built fine and with just one specific solution MacAgent was just disconnecting shortly after build was started.

Answer (score 0):

So after my working day was totally messed up finally i found the cause: a small file without extension i just added to project yesterday to take a quick text note was causing this pain. Once file was excluded - disconnects were gone.

Hope this might help someone!

**EDIT:** **FIXED by Xamarin team**